# How to Highlight the variation form fields on variable product page in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I have created a variable product with size and color attributes. It is working fine.

when user doesn't select any option (Attribute) and tries to add product to cart it does not let him to add product to the cart. Also it shows error message in the form of JavaScript alert box.

This scenario is working great but now the client wants that if user has not selected any attribute or option and clicks add to cart button then the attribute fields should be highlighted in RED color.

If someone only selects the size and does not select the color and clicks add to cart then only color should be highlighted in RED and if user has not selected both the attribute then both attribute must be highlighted in RED?

[image]

Comment: I don't have any code for it. everything working till now was in the default theme.

Comment: This is possible with CSS and jQuery, but in order to give an appropriate answer, a url will be required to the page, because otherwise we cannot determine which html tag contains which CLASS selector.

Comment: https://waqasyousuf.com/new-testing/product/product-1/

This is the URL